# Will Ubuntu 13.10 work fine on my netbook?? or should i choose some previos version?

Tags: system-installation

I'm new to Linux, just downloaded Ubuntu 13.10 and finally decided to switch to Linux.

Is My Hp Mini Net book with Intel(R) Atom CPU N455 @ 1.67 Ghz , 2GB RAM fine to run this OS smoothly or should i choose someone else?
I mean won't I be missing the new fun going on Linux if i choose older one.?

Answer (score 0):

Your computer should be able to run Ubuntu 13.10 fine.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you that when downloading Ubuntu you get the 32 bit version as they now offer to download the 64 bit version by default. If it doesn't run as you expect you could also try:

http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/